# Issue installing package after FIPS enabled

Tags: apt, package-management

Recently installed 20.04 and enabled FIPS and then attempted to install a package called ffmpeg but it fails.
I attempted to install the same package on a laptop with 20.04 and had no issues.

Has anyone come across this type of issue shown below:

```
sudo apt install ffmpeg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ffmpeg : Depends: libavdevice58 (= 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libavresample4 (= 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libsdl2-2.0-0 (>= 2.0.10) but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04 : Depends: linux-image-5.11.0-38-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-modules-5.11.0-38-generic : Depends: linux-image-5.11.0-38-generic but it is not going to be installed or linux-image-unsigned-5.11.0-38-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-38-generic : Depends: linux-image-5.11.0-38-generic but it is not going to be installed or linux-image-unsigned-5.11.0-38-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libfprint-2-tod1 shim
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-image-5.11.0-38-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc | linux-hwe-5.11-source-5.11.0 linux-hwe-5.11-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-5.11.0-38-generic
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
7 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/9,912 kB of archives.
After this operation, 10.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 238096 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-5.11.0-38-generic_5.11.0-38.42~20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-5.11.0-38-generic (5.11.0-38.42~20.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.11.0-38-generic_5.11.0-38.42~20.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-38-generic.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.11.0-38-generic_5.11.0-38.42~20.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Greatly appreciate your input!
Lrios

Comment: did you try sudo dpkg --configure -a ?
I usually get it from LFS compiling FFmpeg https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/cvs/multimedia/ffmpeg.html
FFmpeg is a solution to record, convert and stream audio and video. It is a very fast video and audio converter and it can also acquire from a live audio/video source. Designed to be intuitive, the command-line interface (ffmpeg) tries to figure out all the parameters, when possible. FFmpeg can also convert from any sample rate to any other, and resize video on the fly with a high quality polyphase filter. FFmpeg can use a Video4Linux compatibl

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it appears to have issues with the kernel..   
dpkg: error processing package linux-generic-hwe-20.04 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-modules-5.11.0-38-generic
 linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04
 linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-38-generic
 linux-generic-hwe-20.04

Comment: Setting up linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04 (5.11.0.38.42~20.04.17) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic-hwe-20.04:
 linux-generic-hwe-20.04 depends on linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04 (= 5.11.0.38.42~20.04.17); 
  Package linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04 is not configured yet
dpkg: error processing package linux-generic-hwe-20.04 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-modules-5.11.0-38-generic
 linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04
 linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-38-generic
 linux-generic-hwe-20.04